# how to replicate the deployment of multiple instances of the same php application in web server

Tags: php, mysql

Im not very skilled in php. I have a simple php application ready for deployment. I want to avoid repetitive tasks of sending the same files and filling the database credentials. i just want to know what the methoddology to automate such job.thanks.

Comment: could you please add your code whatever you have done so far

Comment: This is best expressed as a search for "php deployment tools" in your nearest search engine.

Comment: @Mayur Satav sorry but i have no idea. now the only solution i see is to copy paste the files and refill the db config.

Comment: thanks @tadman. good orientation.

Comment: Unfortunately questions like this are really hard to answer concisely, we can't really assess your specific needs in this strict question-answer model. If you're having trouble with a specific deployment  method then it's on-topic if you can provide technical details, otherwise it's off-topic here. This is not to say it's a bad question, it's just a bad fit for this forum.